# Image Capture (macOS Monetery) - How to Force Refresh *Contents*

Tags: macos, ios, monterey, image-capture

I have my iPhone connected to my Mac continously (I am a iOS developer). If Image Capture is already running on my Mac and I take a screenshot/recording on my iPhone then quite often (not always however) Image Capture does not update/refresh the device contents and the new screenshots/videos and not available for download.

The only way I am currently able to force Image Capture to refresh the contents of the connected device is to unplug and replug its USB cable.

Does anyone know of a way I might force Image Catpure to refresh the contents without having to pull the cable?

PS:

- Restarting Image Capture does not work
- I am NOT trying to refresh the list of devices itself

Comment: It's a problem since 2011 :( and not fixed yet